# Is there a concept similar to lazy/greedy/posessive for the start of a capture group?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to capture malformed segments of html using lazy quantifier without success:

```
<p>ok</p> <p>malformed</b></p>
```

is captured as whole using `<p>(.+?)</b></p>` - not only the second part.

This is what I get from the notepad++ regex engine. But I noticed the same behavior in phpStorm as well.

I always thought, lazy will take the minimal part. So I deducted from what I've seen, that laziness/greediness/possessiveness is exclusively about the ending of segment. Is there a similar concept for the start of a capture group?

**Please, do not post answers to the capture problem itself, I am interested in the theoretical side of this whole. Thank you!**

Comment: Why is there so much polarity on reputation with this question? Because obviously unimplemented?

Comment: I've never read of such concept. It could be due to the general **forward-direction** matching of regex engine, but it can be replicated (in your case) by using `<p>([^<]+)</b></p>`. I hope some future implementations might introduce this thing!

Comment: What do you mean by _`capture problem`_ ? There is only 1 capture group https://regex101.com/r/RNSFbQ/1. Example: lazy optional quantifiers `.*?` don't try to match right away, they check the next regex char/meta-char to see if it can match that. If it does, it skips the `.*?` and it is satisfied. If not a match, it _consumes_ a character and advances the position, then repeats. The lazy required quantifier `.+?` does the same except consumes a character first, then does the check, then repeats if necessary. I think you might be conflicted about how to control backtracking, which is an art.

Comment: @rv7 yes, thank you, that's what I have thought as well. I just wanted to point it out and give that idea a bit of publicity.

Comment: @sln you see, the regex engine consumes characters at it looks for end of capture group, but it also collects alternative beginnings of the group it currently scans for at the same time - in case it should fail and must backtrack. So in the internal state, there co-exist the first opening, but as well the alternative, later openings. To take the first or last matching *opening* is a dual concept to lazy/greedy.

Comment: @informatik-handwerk.de - Sorry my friend, it is a left to right proposition. First come, first served to the finish line. Is only 1 Last good backtrack position, nothing else is kept. Basically, a single state thread through the space.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this mate**

Yes regex do have policies like greedy and lazy. `<p>.*?</b></p>`your regex will match `<p>` first and than keep on matching until it find the `</b>`.
To understand look at this regex.

```
<p>.*?<\/p>
```

So this regex will try to match `<p>` to next `</p>`.

if you remove `?` it will try to match `<p>` to last `</p>`.

> Working one

```
<p>\w+?<\/b><\/p>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AuJfo2/1)

Comment: Please, do not post answers to the capture problem itself, I am interested in the theoretical side of this whole. Thank you!